# rst2pdf header / footer text color

Tags: css, restructuredtext, rst2pdf

How can I change the header / footer text color in the style sheet?

I tried, fruitlessly:

```
footer: {
  parent: normal,
  alignment: TA_CENTER,
  textColor: red
},
```

Comment: This is not so much a reStructuredText question but a CSS question. Adding this tag will have probably gotten this answered sooner.

Comment: No, this is not a CSS question because he's asking about rst2pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header or footer are not really styled that way because they are arbitrary restructured text.

So, if you want to change the color, the easiest way is probably to use a class, or a role.

So, you could do:

```
.. footer::

   class:: foo

   This is the footer, with style foo
```

Or

```
.. footer::

   :foo:`This is the footer with style foo`
```

If you do the latter, you will have to add a

```
.. role:: foo
```

somewhere.